# Why does one kitten love his toy, but the another one is scared of it?

Tags: cats, behavior, fear

So I just got two kittens a few days ago, and they have both been doing fine. I just got a new toy for them, a fish pole toy with a furry thing on it. I was pleased because the much shyer one, Truman, was obsessed with it, I mean OBSESSED. I put it on my desk and he wouldn't stop meowing till I took it down.

The weird thing is that my other kitten, Schroeder, is super playful and always attacking everything and is never shy, refuses to play with it! He is almost scared of it. He just likes to sit up high and watch his brother play with it. Is this anything I should be worried about or am I just being silly?

Comment: Do you know if they have been previously exposed to similar toys if any before?

Answer (score 4):

Doesn't sound like anything to worry about... cats will perceive toys very differently to humans but like humans they all have their own likes/dislikes/fears and it's not unusual for the same toy or object to evoke very different responses in different cats. Sometimes watching a fellow cat play with a particular toy *is* the entertainment the cat gets from something so it's all good.

If the kittens are very young (and your question sort of implies they are) then you may well see Schroeder gradually joining in playing with the fishing pole toy over the next couple of days but if he doesn't he doesn't and I wouldn't worry.

Comment: Both kittens may enjoy it if you secure the wand on a table or similar (put a large book on it). have the fluffy bit at chest/nose height for the kitten. Part of reason it is off putting for Schroeder may be how much it moves. By having it hanging he can bat at it, moving it on his own terms.

Answer (score 1):

I think Schroeder in even more younger days may have had some very fearful experience which involved some furry thing. It remains in his memory. And the current furry toy reminds him of the event. He is associating the furry thing with bad experience he once had.

I suggest removing the furry toy completely, so that he doesn't have to always relive the horror. And give him time to forget the experience.

Comment: I don't believe Schroeder is truly _scared_  I would expect him to run away and hide from it if that was the case.